# Distribution of sign in term $-(3x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If there is $(4x+3)-(3x-1)$
We evaluate it to $4x+3-3x+1$.

Like we are multiplying $-1(3x-1)$

Why this works what's the fundamental of it like in math there's always proof of why this is always true?

Comment: Yes, 1 is  a *neutral element of multiplication*. So you always can add a factor 1 without changing the term. $-(3x-1)=-1\cdot (3x-1)$.

Comment: I like to think of it like this:  Subtraction is the inverse of addition.  When you apply inverse operation twice, you get the original operation.

Comment: Also from the distributive property $-1$ gets multiplied to both of the terms in bracket resulting in $-3x+1$

Comment: To answer this... we have to ask what level you are at, what level of specificity you want, and what you already know.  We could go off talking about field axioms and additive inverses and such, but given the way you have asked this question I expect that may just confuse you further.  The short version is that "subtraction" is just "adding by the 'opposite' of what follows", that is to say $a - b$ is by definition equal to $a + (-b)$ where in this second expression the $-$ sign is not there for subtraction but used to denote "opposite"

Comment: As for why $-(a+b) = -a - b$... notice that $-(a+b)+(a+b) = 0$ and that $-a-b + (a+b) = -a +a - b + b = 0+0 = 0$, so yes we have that $-(a+b)$ and $(-a-b)$ are both the opposite of $(a+b)$ and so must be equal.

Comment: By the distributive property: $-1(3x-1)=-1(3x+-1)=-1(3x) + -1(-1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz "To answer this" I think the question is more about the extra 1 than the change of the signs. I agree to the answer of algevristis.

Comment: @callculus42 to be clear, there is no need to mention or think of an "extra 1."  $(4x+3)-(3x-1) = (4x+3) + (-(3x-1))=(4x+3)+(-3x+1)$.  It can be thought of using the negation symbol rather than thinking using multiplication by negative one.  While it is true that $-x = (-1)\cdot x$, there is no need to have utilized that fact here.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is true what you write. But is not the question of the OP as far as I understand. The question is about the "extra 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are asking why the expression
\begin{align}
- (3x - 1) 
\end{align}
is evaluated as
\begin{align}
- \boxed{ \mathbf{1} \cdot } (3x-1).
\end{align}

If that's the case, then it is standard notation, since in the field of the real numbers the identity element with regards to multiplication is $1$, ie. when it's multiplied by anything it results in the original multiplicated quality.

As regards to a proof of this, it's by definition true, since we say that an element $\alpha$ is the identity element with regards to an operation $*$ if
\begin{align}
\alpha * x = x*\alpha = x, \forall x \in \mathbb R.
\end{align}

Comment: To use the fact that $1$ is the multiplicative identity, you need to prove that $-1\times x = -(1\times x)$. And that it is not completely trivial.

Comment: Yeah it about the about why it is i still didn't get it

Comment: @FrostFizz  1 is the multiplicative identity. That means $-a=1\cdot (-a)=-1\cdot a$. What is your specific questions?

Comment: @callculus42: How do you know that $1\cdot - a = -1 \cdot a$? Again, this can be proven from the field axioms, but it is by no means a one-line proof.

Comment: @Joe This is no proof. I use the result of the proof.

Comment: I was asking for the proof

Comment: @FrostFizz I overread it. It seems that the most users have overread it. Maybe Joe will provide a proof. Btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @FrostFizz: By definition, $-x$ is the unique number satisfying $-x+x=0$. So we need to show that $(-1\cdot x)+x=0$. To do this, note that
$$
(-1\cdot x)+x=(-1\cdot x)+(1\cdot x)=(-1+1)\cdot x=0\cdot x=0 \, .
$$
Note that this derivation assumes that $0\cdot x=0$. However, *this* can also be proven. Are you interested in a proof of this fact?

Comment: I got it and proof of 0.x =0 yeah sure.

Comment: @FrostFizz: By definition, $0$ satisfies $0+a=a$ for all $a$. Hence, $0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x$. Then, adding $-(0\cdot x)$ to both sides, we get $0=0\cdot x$. By the way, all of these proofs rely on basic axioms—roughly speaking, these are basic assumptions that are taken for granted as true. For example, distributivity, the law which says $a(x+y)=ax+ay$, is an axiom. Here is a [list](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) of axioms about $\mathbb R$, some of which are used in the proofs here.

Comment: Note that there are other axioms about $\mathbb R$, e.g. the completeness property, but these are a lot more complicated than the basic algebraic axioms that are used here.

Comment: Ohh thanks for your help.